# How can I prevent this UserControl's text from falling off the left side of the screen?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Currently when I populate the TextBlock with too much text, specifically `Connecting to Site 26 has a name too long`, it appears like this:

[image]

This is the definition of the UserControl:

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" />
    <TextBlock Name="txtOverlayText" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
</StackPanel>
```

The text is supposed to be centred and if it's too long it should not fall off the left side of the screen, rather it should be be visible on the left side and anything that can't fit on the right side should be replaced with dots, e.g.

```
Connecting to Site 26 has a name t...
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: [TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.texttrimming.aspx)

Comment: correct. Why not supply this as an answer?

Comment: because it's a one line answer, I'm not that big of a point glutton usually but I guess if you're gonna suggest that I do might as well lol. One sec, I'll even try and add some info fluff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so luckily for some time now in most of the xaml based stuff we've had the super handy dandy [TextTrimming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.texttrimming.aspx) ability where you can just slap `TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"` on something and get those friendly dots on the end.

Though just a tip, sometimes a TextBlock's parent panel wont invoke the boundary to make it happen, so you have to slap a Width value on something, or swap the parent panel, like occasionally depending on the layout things like a `StackPanel` have to be substituted with a `Grid` to invoke the trim.

Anyhow, hope this helps, cheers!